# How to search number of backslash

Tags: tcl

I have a string like below and I want to know the depth

1. `Assb/vvv/jjj`
2. `Sss/jjk/gyii/fff`

The 1st will give me 3 level and 2nd one will give me 4 level.

How to code and  count number of backslash in tcl?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution is:

```
set item "Sss/jjk/gyii/fff"
set depth [llength [split $item {/}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. Here are two that count slightly different things:

1. Count the `/` characters with `regexp -all`, helped by the fact that `/` is *not* an RE metacharacter:

   ```
   # Always put REs in braces… but in this case it doesn't matter much
   set count [regexp -all {/} $inputString]
   puts "slash count is $count"
   ```

   The `regexp` command usually returns the number of times it has matched things, effectively a boolean without `-all`, but useful in this case. (It can returns the details of what it matched with the `-inline` option, but in this case we don't care about that.)
2. Count the number of items that `/` characters separate with `split` and `llength`:

   ```
   set count [llength [split $inputString "/"]]
   puts "chunk count is $count"
   ```

   This reports one more than the method with `regexp`.

I've not `time`d either of these approaches.

---

If these are filenames, use `file split` instead.

```
set count [llength [file split $inputFilename]]
```

That handles some edge cases in filename parsing that you are almost certainly ignorant of. (I know I'm ignorant of many of them too… which is why I'm happy to have the `file split` command take care of it.)